# How to get the first and last date of the previous week?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the *last week's first and last date*. 
My code gets the current week's first and last date.

```
var curr = new Date;
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()));
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()+6));
```

Comment: Made from your code... Not sure about how much valid is it.... http://jsfiddle.net/C5Dj8/

Comment: can you add libraries to use? if so, http://momentjs.com/ will give you all you need for working with dates & time.

Answer (score 3):

What ever the day you run the program it will just give the last week start and end dates.

```
 var date= new Date();
 var dummy =  date.getDay();
 dummy = dummy + 7;
 date.setDate(date.getDate() - dummy );
 alert("previous week first day : "+ date);
 date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
 alert("previous week lastday : "+ date);
```

Best of Luck.